# Need only S3 updated Key Object in Mail : SNS topic is sending whole Json

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-sns

How can I get only Updated S3 Key object data from SNS topic subscription mail

```
{
  "Records": [
    {
      "eventVersion": "2.0",
      "eventSource": "aws:s3",
      "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
      "eventTime": "2018-01-27T01:24:43.660Z",
      "eventName": "ObjectCreated:Put",
      "userIdentity": {
        "principalId": "AWS:AIDAJNQE6"
      },
      "requestParameters": {
        "sourceIPAddress": "98.210.xxx.xxx"
      },
      "responseElements": {
        "x-amz-request-id": "D464A8CB49C8D082",
        "x-amz-id-2": "8g8K1G6b5sSUaxdZyshgxpk2wZR9hUSmj="
      },
      "s3": {
        "s3SchemaVersion": "1.0",
        "configurationId": "Radhikas3update",
        "bucket": {
          "name": "Radhika-test",
          "ownerIdentity": {
            "principalId": "AG737Y2"
          },
          "arn": "arn:aws:s3:::radhika-test"
        },
        "object": {
          "key": "test.txt",
          "size": 14,
          "eTag": "12b9d85febf",
          "sequencer": "005A6B"
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I get only Updated S3 Key object data from SNS topic subscription mail

```
         ********Expecting Output*****************


    "object": {
          "key": "test.txt",
          "size": 14,
          "eTag": "12b9d85febf",
          "sequencer": "005A6B"
             }
```

Please help approach to get only key value in mail

Comment: What are you doing to get the output you get right now?

Comment: Did not get any Idea thinking to write Lambda instead of SNS

Answer (score 0):

There are no true 'directories' in S3, because S3 is an object store, and each object has a single key.  An S3 bucket is basically a set of key-value pairs.

It is typical to use keys that are somewhat 'namespaced', to allow them to look like directories through.  The AWS Console gives the impression of a directory filesystem by breaking up the keys by these namespace components.

For example, I might have a key like this: `com/stackoverflow/nicholas.hauschild/secrets.txt`, and the AWS console would give the impression that there is a 'file' called `secrets.txt` in the directory `com/stackoverflow/nicholas.hauschild/`.

In your example, I see no directory, as the key is simply `test.txt`.

If you were to use my example 'namespaced' key in your example json, it would look like this:

```
    ...
    "object": {
      "key": "com/stackoverflow/nicholas.hauschild/secrets.txt",
      "size": 99999999999999,
      "eTag": "12345",
      "sequencer": "67890"
    }
    ...
```

At this point you will see that you simply need to look at the `key` in your JSON and process the 'directory' from there its value.

Comment: In Mail We want to see only  "object": {
          "key": "test.txt",
          "size": 14,
          "eTag": "12b9d85febf",
          "sequencer": "005A6B"
        }

Comment: "object": {
                       "key": "test.txt",
                       "size": 14,
                       "eTag": "12b9d85febf",
                       "sequencer": "005A6B"
                   }